# aws cloudfront api endpoint responding with Forbidden(403)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function behind an api gateway. This is working fine when triggered with an **Invoke URL**. Invoke URL is the link offered in method tab under stages.

[image]

I am sending request to the resource as below, and this works fine.
[image]

I want to set a custom domain for my api so I followed the standard procedure to set an ACM certificate. In addition to that I did set domain (api.tarkshala.com) in route53. Check screenshots given below.

ACM certificate imported
[image]

Custom domain mapping
[image]

Domain name mapped in route53
[image]

But when I hit the API using cloudfront link(d3pn2j4magp6tp.cloudfront.net) or the domain name (api.tarkshala.com) using POSTMAN, it ends up into **403 Forbidden**.

I don't know what exactly am I missing?

Response Header looks as following:

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →23
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Fri, 13 Apr 2018 03:17:25 GMT
Via →1.1 a1cf0e6cf29b584b5fe1ada9ccee9758.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id →9Jh5HeQIuDNfm5WGlTae34oYZ7BiN3nI2VlH_8PJHLQ0mr2C20njJQ==
X-Cache →Error from cloudfront
x-amz-apigw-id →FQoiyF1phcwFVrg=
x-amzn-ErrorType →ForbiddenException
x-amzn-RequestId →3013c239-3ec9-11e8-abe6-53449bcfc96c
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Comment: You are missing the period in the end of your `Alias Target` in `Route 53`. Try to add it: `d3pn2j4magp6tp.cloudfront.net.` - If this still doesnt work how did you configure your "Base Path Mappings"? Please click on "Show Base Path Mappings" in `API Gateway` (the 3. screenshot)

Comment: The period should not matter.  If Route 53 can't validate the alias target, it should be rejected.  Verify that the `Host` header in the request from postman is set to your custom domain name (not the cloudfront hostname)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot By `Host` header do you mean the url? Or there should be some field in Request Headers? 
@MaiKaY I updated the `API Gateway` screenshot.

Comment: When you make an HTTP request, the hostname in the URL is copied to a header, `Host:`, which you should be able to see in the request headers.  This needs to be your custom domain name, not the cloudfront.net target hostname.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are right. It worked when invoked with https://api.tarkshala.com/drop
Two things I forgot while invoking:
* I didn't give the path /drop
* My basic understanding was that it will work with both abcexample.cloudfront.net and api.tarkshala.com but cloudfront resource link is not public.

Comment: Right.  I wrote an answer, earlier, explaining the difference ans providing some insights... but then I had second thoughts about posting it, since you had mentioned that your custom domain wasn't working either, which was unexpected.  I've posted it, now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation doesn't seem to mention an important aspect of the configuration of the CloudFront distribution associated with an API Gateway endpoint... it seems it can only be inferred:

> When you create a custom domain name for an edge-optimized API, API Gateway sets up a CloudFront distribution. But **you must set up a DNS record to map the custom domain name to the CloudFront distribution domain name [in order] for API requests bound for the custom domain name to be [correctly] routed to API Gateway through the mapped CloudFront distribution [and understood when they arrive]**. You must also provide a certificate for the custom domain name. *(emphasis added, bracketed words are mine, added for clarity)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Internally, CloudFront distributions have two ways of handling the `Host` header that arrives on the incoming request -- CloudFront can hand over the `Host` header submitted by the browser, if it is on a list of expected values, or can always pass a single static value to the back-end origin that it infers from the origin configuration.

For the CloudFront distributions managed by API Gateway, the configuration is apparently to pass through what the browser sends, which makes a good deal of sense because the other alternative would require API Gateway to engage in additional manipulation of the incoming request that would be convoluted and complicated, to say the very least.

Thus, to test a custom domain name on an API Gateway deployment, the requester must include the custom domain name as the HTTP `Host` header.   The cloudfront.net alias target hostname is used *only* for DNS mapping -- it isn't an alternate hostname that API Gateway actually associates with your deployed stage when processing incoming requests.

If your custom domain name is pointed to the "target" domain name in DNS, and you access the API via the custom domain, this all happens automatically.  Otherwise, you can set the `Host` header manually, for testing, if the tool you are using will allow it.

Comment: So for my case, should it be key as `Host` and value to be `api.tarkshala.com`?

Comment: I tried above Key value pairs and it works. Changing value to anything else ends up into connection error.

Comment: Experimented. Even when I use d3pn2j4magp6tp.cloudfront.net to invoke, it works if I have specified `Host` to be `api.tarkshala.com`

Comment: The same, adding to headers Host: api.mydomain.com solved the issue!

Comment: Literally spent a whole day trying to figure this stuff out, thanks for the answer!